# Bluetooth notification for incoming file

Tags: bluetooth, security

recently I wanted to send one file from my phone to my Ubuntu 18.04 notebook, everything went well except that the PC didn't ask me if I wanted to recieve the file, it just began recieving. What if that was some malicious file named same as the file I wanted to send(MITM attack, or something)?

Is that normal?

Comment: Is your phone a trusted Bluetooth device on the computer?

Comment: Sounds like you've already paired your phone to the PC, and allowed the two to communicate, so it doesn't need to ask to allow receipt of the file.